# Show ActionBar in Android PhoneGap project

Tags: android, cordova, android-actionbar

I'm working on an Android PhoneGap solution where I want to use the Native ActionBar to show a few menu options, but somehow the actionbar is not showing. I'm thinking that PhoneGap is hiding it somewhere, but I can't find the solution to unhide it again.

I found some posts where they said that in the OnCreate method I have to set the ShowTitle property to true before the super.OnCreate method is called.

Tried it like below:

```
super.setBooleanProperty("ShowTitle", true);
```

But above method is deprecated. Also tried it in the config.xml file like below:

```
<preference name="ShowTitle" value="true"/>
```

No luck so far.

Also tried it with requestWindowFeature:

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
```

I'm kind of out of options to think how to get this ActionBar visible.

I'm using PhoneGap version 3.3.0
And testing it on the emulator with Android 4.0 API level 14 based on the Nexus 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, found it. In my manifest the Activity has the theme set to android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" removed the theme and the action bar is there.

Comment: I am getting the ActionBar cordova.getActivity().getActionBar(); which always return null. Is there any other manifest settings need to be updated?

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same problem today, and I found another way to solve it, at least it worked for me. In config.xml I set this:

```
<preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />
```

Fullscreen from true to false. Hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Add property in Theme style xml

```
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
```